# Problem in Supporting Multiple Screens in Android?

Tags: android

Hai Friends,
            I have developed an application which en-composes list views and posted that .apk file in my htc device, the design and alignment everything works fine,but the problem When  i am testing  in various devices such as Morotolo Droid,Nexus Devices the alignment of Listviews goes wrong, so i planned to use the Layout folder as layout-hdpi,layout-ldpi, and layout-mdpi, for that i changed my manifest file as

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Is it right putting android:anyDensity="true",also i used dp instead of dip. I went through this url, but still am not able to get a clear idea in this 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. so friends pls tell me(help me) to get clear idea in this and tell what mistakes i have doing. This is my main page xml code frnds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_retinav2">   

     <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:foregroundGravity="bottom" android:background="@color/white" android:id="@+id/rl_1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView  android:paddingTop="3dp" android:id="@+id/starthideimage" android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="35dp" android:src="@drawable/newback" />
        <HorizontalScrollView  android:paddingTop="8dp" android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_weight="1" android:foregroundGravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/san_tag" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageView  android:paddingTop="3dp" android:id="@+id/Endhideimage" android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="35dp" android:src="@drawable/newforward" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="fill_parent">



         <ListView android:id="@+id/content_movies" android:cacheColorHint="@color/cachecolor" 
           android:layout_weight="1" android:scrollbars="vertical"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="420dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>   
 </LinearLayout>

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:listSelector="@color/gray"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

</TabHost>
```

Comment: The problem is likely in your layout. So I recommend you to post it here if you want to get help. android:anyDensity="true" means that you support all screen resolutions and android 1.6+. There is no point having  android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" if you have android:anyDensity="true".

Comment: @ Mr.Cement: can u pls go through again, i have posted my main page xml content for ur refernce friend. i have one dobut if i used layout height  as fill_parent or wrap_content the listview content is hide in Morotolo android device and Nexus device, that's y i manually changing the height and put that values in layout-hdpi and layout-ldpi and layout-mdpi. Is it right??? pls tell me

Comment: The Fighter: You have not said what your problem is. We cannot help you if all you tell is is "the alignment of Listviews goes wrong". The phrase "goes wrong" is not very specific. Consider using screenshots from DDMS to document your problem. Also, if your "alignment" is of the contents of the rows, you will need to give us the row layout XML, not the activity layout XML. And, you might consider first using `hierarchyviewer` to try to determine whether your layout rules are behaving as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should get width and height of device on run time

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
screenWidth = display.getWidth();
screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

And the make your layout accordingly

If you can code your layout programatically instead of using xml

It'd be best practice

Comment: That is not the best practice for Android. If at all possible, you should design your layout in XML, to keep the code separate from the layout. Naturally in some instances you will have to make layout changes at runtime, but in most cases XML is the preferred way to set your layout.

Comment: so you trying to say that for different devices we should make plenty of XML files?. why not just make one method for the layout and change it on run time. for dynamic work you have to work without XML.

Comment: this answer is terribly incorrect. there's a reason why android has the different folder-names feature - to automatically check the size and density of the screen, and inflate the correct layout accordingly. and yes, kcoppock is trying to say we should make as many xml files as needed for a different screen density/size - if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Android does work better with the separate folder name schema and thusly the XML style sheets for layout there within although it makes for a little longer load time rather than using a dynamically linked single XML or direct code module dynamically updated from that old Linux method of acquiring screen specs
However if you could determine whether the devices you have problems with perhaps have a glithcy screen size report process as some devices hide system touch buttons and/or the bar with the clock, WiFi icon, data network type icon, etc hidden to some extent to many programs as per example a 1024x600 may report as 1024x552 or 976x600 because the 48pixel status bar is hidden from get screen height and width commands as antutu uses that approach
Thus in some heirachy systems it sees 1024x600 then suddenly actual space is 976x600 or 1024x552. For 1280x800 displays this can be 1216x800 or 1280x736 as the 64pixel status bar is not unanimously included in screen size reporting. This is merely a suggestion not necessarily a remedy to your problem as said earlier by someone getting screenshots will help a lot if the problem is graphical not due to frame formatting which is different matter depending on how your app is deigned to display the list data ie whether the list data is direct list view with padding params or contained within a convenient frame first